# Java JList remove() method throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm using a JList which displays correctly. However, I'm having trouble removing elements from the list.

```
JList nameList = new JList(db.getAllNames());
nameList.setVisibleRowCount(6);
nameList.setFixedCellWidth(400);

JButton removeNameButton = new JButton("Remove Name");

removeNameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String id = nameList.getSelectedValue().toString(); //valid value when button pressed
        int index = nameList.getSelectedIndex(); //valid value when value pressed

        namesList.remove(index); //ERROR
    }
```

The JList contains 4 names, which displays perfectly and seem to have the correct indexes. (If I check the value `System.out.println(copiersList.getModel().getSize());` it always displays 4

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 3
```

Oddly, if I remove Adam, I do not get an error (but visibly the list does not change and calling `.getSize()` method displays 4):

[image]

```
id selected: Adam
index selected: 0
```

However, any other:

```
id selected: BobException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
index selected: 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1
at java.awt.Container.remove(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't remove from the JList itself since the `remove(...)` method does not do what you think that it does. It in fact is trying to remove a component that is held in the JList as if it were a JPanel that held other components, even if no such component exists. Instead remove from the JList's ***model***, usually a DefaultListModel. The DefaultListModel class has a `removeElement(Object element)` and a `removeElementAt(int index)` method that can help you.

i.e.,.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String id = nameList.getSelectedValue().toString(); //valid value when button pressed
    int index = nameList.getSelectedIndex(); //valid value when value pressed

    DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) namesList.getModel();
    listModel.removeElementAt(index); 
}
```

Comment: Basically the `listModel` is a simple data structure which holds all the elements (hence remove, add methods etc) and the `JList` simply displays the data from the `DefaultListModel`? (Is this correct?)

Comment: @gudthing: I look on the JList as the view and the ListModel as the model. The model holds the state of the object, here the list of items, and the view displays this state. If you change the state of the model, then this change should be reflected in the view.

Comment: Which self-explains the JList dynamically updating when the state (of the model) changes. Thanks again for your reply, I think I got this :)